# Merge two Jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded two scripts from the net,

one looks like this

```
<script src="jqzoom/js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jqzoom/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqzoom/css/jquery.jqzoom.css" type="text/css">

<script>
$(function () {     
            $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
            zoomType: 'standard',
            lens:true,
            preloadImages: false,
            alwaysOn:true
        });
});
</script>
```

and the other

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="booklet/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script> window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="booklet/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.latest.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {     
            $("#mybook").booklet();
        });
    </script>
```

When I place both in one page only the latter works, however individually they work fine.

I understand you can't call jQuery twice within the same page, but when I remove all the jQuery additions and just use /jquery.js none of them work. This is the scripts as I downloaded them, I figured the HTML between them is not needed to post here.

How can I make both work on one page?

Comment: You're including several versions of jQuery. Try sticking to one of them.

Comment: It is difficult to say. The scripts can have conflicting hooks. I would take one and build off on it. Rarely can you just copy and dump code and have it work perfectly. Also, I suggest you use the latest jquery version for both. It should be backwards compatible. Loading jquery twice is definitely asking for trouble.

Comment: He's using plugins - you can't tell him to simply use 1 version of jQuery without knowing if the plugins require specific versions.  It's not helpful to make assumptions.

Comment: @MihaiIorga that's done it, although the flipbook lost a function which just creases the page before it turns. I think I need to read more into it. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 2 js libraries in first script and 4 to the second script. All the libraries essential to run their respective scripts.

One problem here is, you are adding jQuery twice which is 1.6 and 2.1. Which is unnecessary.

Try doing like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="booklet/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script> window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="booklet/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.latest.js"></script>

    //required for first script
    <script src="jqzoom/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqzoom/css/jquery.jqzoom.css" type="text/css">
    //-------------

    <script>
        $(function () {     
            //this is your second script
            $("#mybook").booklet();

            //this is your first script
            $(function () {     
                $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
                zoomType: 'standard',
                lens:true,
                preloadImages: false,
                alwaysOn:true
            });

        });
    </script>
```

This should keep your second script running. And if first doesn't run then it means 'jqzoom' plugin is not compatible with jquery 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Most problems from older jQuery versions are solved in their [Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin), you should check that out.

Just add the newest version and that plugin and your scripts should theoretically work.

Answer (score -1):

with all other library include j query standard librery at once.

```
<script src="jqzoom/js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jqzoom/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqzoom/css/jquery.jqzoom.css" type="text/css">
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="booklet/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
<script> window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="booklet/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {     
            $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
            zoomType: 'standard',
            lens:true,
            preloadImages: false,
            alwaysOn:true
        });

        $("#mybook").booklet();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like the booklet plugin requires jQuery 2.  Version 1.6 most certainly won't be enough for it.